# Dapper 'Characters found after end of SQL statement.' - Stop Dapper returning identity value

Tags: ms-access, dapper, petapoco

I'm using Dapper with Microsoft Access (not by choice I assure you) and I'm also using the Dapper.Contrib extensions to allow me to do `connection.Insert(address)`.  Unfortunately that's throwing an error `'Characters found after end of SQL statement.'` because, I'm assuming, the SQL dapper generates is doing the insert and then asking for `SCOPE_IDENTITY` and Access doesn't like multiple SQL statements separated by a `;`.

Is there any way to tell Dapper not to try and return the identity value?

I've had a look at the [source code for the Dapper.Contrib](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/blob/master/Dapper.Contrib/SqlMapperExtensions.cs) and it looks like I'm probably out of luck?

Answer (score 0):

So as an update on this:  I couldn't get Dapper.Contrib to work nicely with Access, so in the end I switched from Dapper to [PetaPoco](http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/).  That's been live on the production system for a while now and has behaved very well with Access.

One very useful aspect of PetaPoco is that rather than being a compiled DLL, you actually just add a single PetaPoco.cs file to your project, which makes debugging much easier.

Other micro-ORMs are available etc., but PetaPoco has been a good solution for use with Microsoft Access thus far.

Comment: "I couldn't get Dapper to work nicely with Access" this is not correct. Dapper works correctly with Access. What does not work is "Dapper.Contrib". I was planning to use DapperExtensions with Access. Faced many problems and finally decided to switch database. I am lucky, that was possible and allowed by business. Technical work to switch database was negligible. Issue was backward compatibility.

Comment: @AmitJoshi good point, I've updated my answer.  If there had been any way to switch database I definitely would of; working with MS Access has been painful.